# Using `lean` on mongoose queries that return arrays in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have two Mongoose queries and decided it would be best to use `.lean()` on them.

For the one that returns a single document, it seems to work fine:

```
let something:Something;
SomethingDocument.findOne({_id:theId}).lean().then( (res) => { something = res;});
```

The problem is when I try to use it with a query that returns multiple results:

```
let somethings:Something[];
SomethingDocument.find({color:'blue'}).lean().then( (res) => { somethings = res;});
```

The second call gives the error:

```
Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Something[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'length' is missing in type 'Object'.
```

If I try to do a type conversion it just complains the the 'length' property is missing in type 'Object'.

How do I use `lean` when I expect an array of results?

...note that if I simply omit `lean` it all works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mongoose type definitions are not so good IMHO, so you can fix it using this:

```
let somethings:Something[];
SomethingDocument.find({color:'blue'}).lean().then((res) => { somethings = res as any;});
```

And by the way, I would suggest to use `await` if you are able to (you have to compile TS to a modern Ecma version):

```
const somethings = await SomethingDocument.find({color:'blue'}).lean() as Something[];
```

Note that the former version catches errors on .catch, but the second one will throw an exception.

Comment: You know, I actually am using await in that exact situation but didn't want to complicate the question.  I've actually found that using `Promise.all` on an array of returned promises is easier - is there something specific about `await` that you prefer over `Promise.all`?  I guess you have to manage an array of promises but is there any other reason?  Readability?  I'm not against it, as I say - I'm using it - but I haven't made my mind up about it.

Comment: Await introduces syntactic changes in you code. This is a topic for a new whole discussion, so you should better research about its usage and the implications of using it. I pointed it out because is clearer to read and shorter. You can also use `await` with the result of `Promise.all` btw.